# Search and Display ACF Repeater Sub Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type called Players which is generating 8 different players with each of them having 3 videos per player. Each of these video has a title. Let's say "Player A - Running " "Player A - Swimming"

How can I search via keyword in such a way that whenever I type in Player A it only shows me the videos of the player A. Right now whenever type Player A it displays me all the videos in the search Result

```
<?php
$s=($_GET["s"]); // Insert the searched keyword into a variable
// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('videos') ):
// loop through the rows of data
while ( have_rows('videos') ) : the_row(); 
    $video_1_title= get_sub_field('video_1_title');
    $video_2_title= get_sub_field('video_2_title');
    $video_3_title= get_sub_field('video_3_title');
    $video_1= get_sub_field('video_1');
    $video_2= get_sub_field('video_2');
    $video_3= get_sub_field('video_3');
    ?>

 <?php 
 endwhile;
 endif;
 ?>

 <?php if ( have_posts() ) :
 while ( have_rows('videos') ) : the_row(); ?>

 <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="videoPosts">

 <?php
  if(stripos($video_1_title, $_GET["s"])!== false) ||       
 (stripos($video_2_title, $_GET["s"])!== false) ||
 (stripos($video_3_title, $_GET["s"])!== false)) :

 ?>

<div id="one"><?php echo $video_1?></div>
<div id="two"><?php echo $video_2?></div>
<div id="three"><?php echo $video_3?></div>


<?php endif; ?>
</div>

<?php 
endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you confirm what page is this on? For example is it an archive, a single etc? I'm justtrying to figure out what your `$post` is

Comment: it is a search.php page. I am building a custom search.php page with a specific design that will display all the videos, images and descriptions in a separate sections.

I am just unable to display individual posts that contain that specific value. For example when you type "John" it should show all the images, videos and description about john in a separate section. Right now it displays all the videos but puts "John's" videos on the top of search results page.

Comment: And they are just regular posts i.e. you are not using a Custom Post Type? I'm fairly sure I know the problem, but I just want to get all the info before I suggest a solution!

Comment: I am using ACF Pro and I have created a post type called "Players" which contains a repeater field called videos which contains 3 subfields called video_1_title, video_2_title, video_3_title.

Comment: Yes, but are those fields being added to a regular Wordpress post, a page, or a custom post type?

Comment: They are added to single-player.php template.

Comment: So you have a custom post type called `player`?

Comment: Yes. the custom post type is equal to player

Comment: Still no luck with the output. Still displaying all the player videos

Comment: "Yes. the custom post type is equal to player" - thats was what I was trying to find out :). Basically your logic is wrong. I'm working on something at the moment but give me some time and I'll get back to you with a solution.

Comment: Appreciated buddy

Comment: Ok, I'm back :) So, you are trying to get the search to work with custom fields in a custom post type. How should your search deal with other post types? e.g. should your search *only* search your `player` posts, or do you want it to show any results in any post type, and if it appears in a `player` post, then show the videos? It is actually quite difficult to get WP to search custom fields. If you are looking for a specific "video title" search, then we can do that here.

Comment: That is taken care of. I have limited the search to the "Player" post type only.

Comment: I am just looking for the video and video title that is all.

Comment: Just the code which I have posted in the question, i want it do display post ids that contain the searched word. That is all.
You search "swimming", it displays all the posts whose video_title is swimming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that Wordpress doesn't search custom fields by default, which is why you have had to write your own search code for the video titles.

Including custom fields in WP's search is actually complicated and you would normally use a plugin like Relevanssi, but as you *only* want to search for videos by title, then that we can do!

You have problems with your loops and logic, but the bigger problem is that Wordpress search only returns results where the keyword exists in standard WP fields (such as post title or the content) and not the ACF fields.

To continue the way you are doing it (i.e. replacing the search in your search.php):

**1. Replace the code you have above from your search.php with the following:**

This uses WP_Query to do a brand new query that searches only the video title for your just for the video titles.

```
$s=($_GET["s"]);

// this will search all `player` posts for the search keyword in a custom field called video_%_title
// you don't need to specify video_1_title, video_2_title etc separately
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'player',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'video_%_title',
            'compare'   => 'LIKE',
            'value'     => $s,
        ),
    )
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// loop through the results
if( $the_query->have_posts() ): 
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 

       // loop through all results to get the videos:
        while ( have_rows('videos') ) : the_row(); ?>

            <div id="post-<?php get_the_ID(); ?>" class="videoPosts">

                <div id="one"><?php echo get_sub_field('video_1'); ?></div>
                <div id="two"><?php echo get_sub_field('video_2'); ></div>
                <div id="three"><?php echo get_sub_field('video_3'); ></div>

            </div>

        <?php 
        endwhile; // end video loop

    endwhile;  // end posts loop
endif; 

wp_reset_query();    // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). 
?>
```

Note:

This displays all the videos in any posts that were found, because that's what your own code does. If you want to show just the ones with the search keyword, you can do this instead:

```
$video_1_title= get_sub_field('video_1_title');
$video_2_title= get_sub_field('video_2_title');
$video_3_title= get_sub_field('video_3_title');

<?php
 if(stripos($video_1_title, $_GET["s"])!== false))  { ?>
     <div id="one"><?php echo get_sub_field('video_1'); ?></div>
<?php 
}
if(stripos($video_2_title, $_GET["s"])!== false))  { ?>
     <div id="two"><?php echo get_sub_field('video_2'); ?></div>
<?php 
}
if(stripos($video_3_title, $_GET["s"])!== false))  { ?>
     <div id="three"><?php echo get_sub_field('video_3'); ?></div>
<?php 
}
?>
```

**2. Add this to your functions.php**

(Although it will work if you include it in your search.php page)
This tells Wordpress to search in all fields called `video_%_title` where % is any number

```
function player_video_posts_where( $where ) {
    $where = str_replace("meta_key = 'video_%", "meta_key LIKE 'video_%", $where);
    return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'player_video_posts_where');
```

Comment: The wp_query option didn't work but the second code did the trick for me for the videos section. Thanks a Lot.